# Prove by induction that 1^k+2^k+...+n^k is of highest degree n^(k+1)/(k+1)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Let $k$ be a positive integer. Prove by induction on $n$ that
>   $$
> \sum_{r=1}^n r( r+1) ( r+2) \cdots( r+k-1) =\frac{n( n+1) (n+2) \cdots(n+k)}{k+1}
> $$
>   Show now by induction on $k$ that
>   $$
> \sum_{r=1}^{n}r^k=\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+E_{k}(n), 
> $$
>   where $E_{k}(n)$is a polynomial in $n$ of degree at most $k$°

The first part is quite straightforward, and I can derive the final result by telescoping, $$\sum_1^{n-1}(r+1) ^k-r^k
$$

But no idea how to derive the result by induction on $k$

Comment: at most k, what that phase means in your question?

Comment: The title is misleading.

Comment: I have tidied up your $\TeX$-ing a bit. Could you please look over it and see whether I made any mistakes? Also, for next time, take a look at my style. You don't need `\left( \right)` on every single parenthesis, and you don't need `\text` on every single variable. And actual text doesn't have to be inside the math mode.

Comment: is that the word "using" or is that some kind of mathematical expression? !

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your advice. As I type all the words in "axmath", a formula typing SW, then it automatically changes the whole text into Tex, I suppose there are lots of useless tex expressions.

Comment: Right. Automatic formula generation makes sense. At any rate, $\TeX$ (or rather MathJax) isn't that difficult to do yourself, unless you want to do something _really_ fancy. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick guide for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no difficulty with the first part (induction on $n$).

For the second part of the question, it is trivial to show the statement is true for $k=1$. Now assume the statement is true for $k \le m$. Then
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r^k=\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+E_{k}(n),\quad \text{for } k\le m.$$

Now let's look at the the case for $m+1$ by making use of the conclusion of the first part at $m+1$.
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r( r+1) ( r+2) \cdots( r+m) =\frac{n( n+1) (n+2) \cdots(n+m+1)}{m+2}. $$

We expand both sides into individual terms  of power of $r$ on the left hand side, and power of $n$ on the right hand side. We got two polynomials of $r$ and $n$, i.e.
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \left( r^{m+1} + a_1r^{m}+\cdots + a_{m}r+a_{m+1} \right) =\frac{n^{m+2} + b_1n^{m+1} \cdots + b_{m+1}n}{m+2}, $$
where $a_i$ and $b_j$ are coefficients from expansion and combining terms of the same degrees. Hence
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^{m+1} + a_1\sum_{r=1}^n r^{m}+\cdots + a_{m}\sum_{r=1}^n r+\sum_{r=1}^n a_{m+1}  =\frac{n^{m+2}}{m+2} + E_{m+1}(n).$$
By applying induction assumptions, we have
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^{m+1} + a_1\left( \frac{n^{m+1}}{m+1}+E_{m}(n) \right)+\cdots a_{m}\left( \frac{n^{1+1}}{1+1}+E_{1}(n) \right)+  a_{m+1}n  =\frac{n^{m+2}}{m+2} + E_{m+1}(n).$$
Note all items of the left hand side except the first one is a polynomial of $n$ with degrees of at most $m+1$. Hence we can write
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^{m+1} + E_{m+1}^\prime(n) = \frac{n^{m+2}}{m+2} + E_{m+1}(n), $$
where $E_{m+1}^\prime(n)$ is a polynomial of $n$ with degrees of at most $m+1$, and the prime signifies it is different from $E_{m+1}(n)$.

Moving $E_{m+1}^\prime(n)$ to the right hand side and merging it with $E_{m+1}(n)$ leads to 
$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^{m+1} = \frac{n^{m+2}}{m+2}  + E_{m+1}''(n),$$ where $E_{m+1}''(n)$ is a polynomial of $n$ with degrees of at most $m+1$.

We just finished showing that the statement is true for $k=m+1$. Hence the statement is proved.